# Android app doesn't build

Tags: android, gradle, protocol-buffers

there is a log after gradle attemp to build project(with protobuf)

> :app:generateDebugProto FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugProto'.
>
>   > protoc: stdout: . stderr: /Users/*/app/build/extracted-protos/main: warning: directory does not exist.   /Users/*/app/src/debug/proto:
>   >     warning: directory does not exist.
>   >     /Users/*/app/build/extracted-protos/debug: warning: directory does not
>   >     exist.   /Users/*/app/build/extracted-include-protos/debug: warning:
>   >     directory does not exist.   /Users/*/app/src/debug/proto: warning:
>   >     directory does not exist.   /Users/*/app/build/extracted-protos/debug:
>   >     warning: directory does not exist.
>   >     /Users/_/app/build/extracted-include-protos/debug: warning: directory
>   >     does not exist.   Missing output directives.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Can't fixed.

Comment: hi there try like this, add apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf' before application plugin declaration in gradle file of app

Comment: try cleaning, rebuilding project with all devices disconnected (if any used for live testing) if not worked then invalidate and restart android studio to see if this works or not. and post you gradle (both app and project) file

Comment: Thanks guys for try to help me out,  but problem was in my project used to java-nano codegen, so after update to protoc 3.0.0 , this cause a problem, so i read https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin and here https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.0.0, that i decided to use java-lite codegen instead of java-nano. And it's clear now, and errors disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys for try to help me out,  but problem was in my project used to java-nano codegen, so after update to protoc 3.0.0 , this cause a problem, so i read https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin and here https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.0.0, that i decided to use java-lite codegen instead of java-nano. And it's clear now, and errors disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Following configuration work for me

Project-level build.gradle file

```
classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.10'
```

App level build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.8.0'
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
        }
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.0.0-pre2'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                remove java
            }
            task.plugins {
                javalite { }
                grpc {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative solution is to create the missing directories manually.
In my case `MyApp/app/build/extracted-include-protos/main` was missing, so I created a "main" folder there, and voila, Error gone.